# Arduino and PCA9685 - Suddenly stopped working

Tags: arduino-uno, power, servo, current, voltage

I'm using an **Arduino Uno** and a **PCA9685** board to run 4 servos (of type MG996R).
For that, I set up the following connections:

- SCL -> SCL
- SDA -> SDA
- Ground -> GT
- VCC -> 3.3V

As the servos require high current under draw, I've used an external power supply that is also connected to the PCA9685 at the intended place. The power supply is at **6V** (DC) - and **max 3 ampere**.

Everything **just worked fine** for about 1 month. Then, suddenly the servos did not move anymore.
What I checked:

- the power supply **still gives** the desired 5-6V at the PCA9685 board
- I bought a **new** PCA9685 board
- I used **another** power supply at 5.2V and max 2 ampere (only 1 servo connected)

The strange thing is that even with the new PCA9685  board and power supply, the **servos don't move**. However, they **move** if a remove the external power supply and connect the **v+** pin of the PCA9685  to the arduino's 5V output pin.

You have any idea whats going on or what might be broken?

Comment: sounds like the external power supply is not powering the PCA9685 board

Comment: It would help if you posted links to each of the hardware devices and a schematic, not a frizzy thing. Do this after you verified that the pull ups for the I2C are correct and all the grounds are connected.